# How to make custom customer attribute filterable in the customer grid?

Tags: magento2, filter, customer-attribute

I've made a patch and this is the code for creating my customer custom attribute:

```
public function apply()
{
    $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();

    /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
    $customerSetup  = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
    $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType(Customer::ENTITY);
    $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

    $attributeSet       = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
    $attributeGroupId   = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

    try {
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            self::CUSTOMER_EMAIL_PREFERENCE,
            [
                'label' => 'Email preferences',
                'input' => 'multiselect',
                'type' => 'text',
                'source' => 'MyVendor\Customer\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source\EmailPreference',
                'required' => false,
                'position' => 333,
                'visible' => true,
                'system' => false,
                'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
                'is_searchable_in_grid' => true,
                'backend' => ''
            ]
        );
    } catch (Exception $error) {
        echo $error->getMessage(); exit();
    }

    $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, self::CUSTOMER_EMAIL_PREFERENCE);
    $attribute->addData([
        'used_in_forms' => [
            'adminhtml_customer',
            'adminhtml_checkout',
            'customer_account_create',
            'customer_account_edit'
        ]
    ]);
    $attribute->addData([
        'attribute_set_id'   => $attributeSetId,
        'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId

    ]);
    $attribute->save();

    $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
}
```

This code creates the customer attribute and all is good, except that it does not appear in the filters! I've added this part:

```
        'is_used_in_grid' => true,
        'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
        'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
        'is_searchable_in_grid' => true,
```

But still doesn't work. Not sure that it is because of the `multiselect` type. I've made a new customer attribute , the only difference is that the `input` 's value is set to `select` . Like: `'input' => 'multiselect',`. In this case I can filter it. Weird!

Would you please share your opinion, advice for this ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I found this workaround:
Create this file, with this path: `app/code/MyVendor/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filters>
    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <column name="{ YOUR CUSTOM CUSTOMER ATTRIBUTE CODE }">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">\MyVendor\MyModule\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source\CustomCustomerAttribute</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email preferences</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">300</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

and in the `\MyVendor\MyModule\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source\CustomCustomerAttribute`, make sure you have this:

```
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource;

class CustomCustomerAttribute extends AbstractSource
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions(): array
    {
        $this->_options = [];
        $this->_options[] = ['label' => 'Label 1', 'value' => 'value1'];
        $this->_options[] = ['label' => 'Label 2', 'value' => 'value2'];
        $this->_options[] = ['label' => 'Label 3', 'value' => 'value3'];

        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find this solution so this is the way i figured it out. In this example i am adding a customer_status column and filtering to the customers grid :

**file**: adminhtml/di.xml:

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection">
    <plugin name="Vendor_Module::AddCustomerStatusFilter"
            type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Ui\Component\CustomersGrid\CustomerGridAddCustomerStatusFilter"/>
</type>
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <plugin name="vendor_customer_grid_add_customer_status"
            type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Ui\Component\CustomersGrid\CustomerGridAddCustomerStatusField"/>
```

**Add status filter plugin:**

```
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Ui\Component\CustomersGrid;

use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection;

class CustomerGridAddCustomerStatusFilter
{

    /**
     * @param Collection $subject
     * @param array|string $field
     * @param array|string|null $condition
     * @throws \Zend_Db_Select_Exception
     */
    public function beforeAddFieldToFilter(Collection $subject, array|string $field, array|string $condition = null)
    {
        if ($field === 'customer_status' && array_key_exists('customer_entity', $subject->getSelect()->getPart('from'))) {
            $field = 'customer_entity.is_active';
        }

        return [
            $field,
            $condition,
        ];
    }
}
```

**Add customer status field plugin:**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Ui\Component\CustomersGrid;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory;

class CustomerGridAddCustomerStatusField
{
    private const CUSTOMER_GRID_TABLE = 'customer_grid_flat';

    public function afterGetReport(CollectionFactory $subject, Collection $collection, $requestName)
    {
        if ($collection->getMainTable() === $collection->getConnection()->getTableName(self::CUSTOMER_GRID_TABLE)) {
            $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                ['customer_entity' => 'customer_entity'],
                'customer_entity.entity_id = main_table.entity_id',
                ['customer_status' => 'customer_entity.is_active'],
            );
        }

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

customer_listing.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <column name="customer_status" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CustomerStatus"
                component="Vendor_Module/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="10">
            <settings>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <options class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CustomerStatus\Options"/>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Customer Status</label>
                <visible>true</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**Filter Options class code:**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CustomerStatus;

use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;

/**
 * Class Options for Listing Column Customer Status
 */
class Options implements OptionSourceInterface
{
    /**
     * Get options
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return [
            [
                'value' => '1',
                'label' => __('Active'),
            ],
            [
                'value' => '0',
                'label' => __('Inactive'),
            ],
            [
                'value' => 'guest',
                'label' => __('Guest'),
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Good luck!